# git status not showing contents of newly added folder

Tags: git

I just created a new git repo at `/` I created a new file`test.txt` in the folder `test_fold` so that the path to the file is `test_fold\test.txt`. I then run `git status`. This is the output, it finds the folder but not the file. Why is not showing me that there is a new file in `test_fold`?

```
$ git status
On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        .gitignore
        test_fold/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

The `.gitignore` file is blank.

Comment: As far as i know, you have to add some placeholders to empty folders, to be synced with git.

Comment: That's just the way Git displays untracked files when the directory doesn't contain any tracked files. Once you have added at least one file inside the directory, `git status` will show individual files inside the folder.

Comment: @Chris so once I add the directory git will scan the contents of the directory?

Comment: @Vader, yes. You can either `git add test_fold/test.txt` to add that specific file, or `git add test_fold` to add all files inside the directory. In this case it amounts to the same thing. Note that Git doesn't track directories at all, so if you try this with an empty folder nothing will get added.

Comment: Is there an actual question? I just see a statement of facts... which look just like they should...

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Git will ignore the content of a folder if the folder doesn't already contain tracked paths. You know by the presence of `test_fold/` that there are files in there (Git will never show you an empty directory as being untracked) and you know that those files are not tracked.

Otherwise, unzipping a folder into your repository could potentially introduce huge amounts of output from `git status`. The default behavior of simply showing the top-level untracked path makes for much saner output.

If you want Git to show you the content of the folder, use

```
$ git status -uall
```

This will show you `test_fold/test.txt` (and any other files) instead of just `test_fold/`.

Comment: It's not actually in my root folder, the important thing was the relative path.

Comment: You said this "Otherwise, unzipping a folder into the root of your repository could potentially introduce huge amounts of output from git status" but my repo is not actually in root

Comment: @Vader Unzipping a folder *anywhere* in your repository is identical to unziipping it into the root. The point is that there is no reason for Git to show you the contents of a directory, if all those contents are untracked.

Answer (score 1):

GIT will never track empty folder, Add a temporary file, so that git will show on `git status`